# Why does sniff never recieve any network traffic? Scapy

Tags: python, network-programming, send, scapy, packet-sniffers

I am using python and scapy on ubuntu.
I have a simple sniff command with a count of one which should terminate as soon as it receives a packet. However this does not happen.

```
 from scapy.all import *

 packet = sniff(count = 1)
 print("a")
```

When run, a never prints, indicating that count never reaches 1. I even try the following to force it to receive a packet. This is run from a separate command prompt after the code above is run.

```
 from scapy.all import *

 send(IP(dst="127.0.0.1")/UDP(dport=5000))
```

But still no luck. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try specifying the interface to sniff.

Comment: This fixed the issue, thanks :D